# Vue-router: Can I get route params value inside route meta?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I need to access the route params from inside the route children meta, so I can do a fetch and get another value. In this example, I want to get the id from params, so I can run a function and get the user name with this id and use it in the meta field. Is this possible?

```
path: '/user/:id', 
component: User,
props: true,
beforeEnter: requireAuth,
children: [
{
    path: '', 
    name: 'user', 
    component: UserOverview,
    meta: {
    breadcrumb: [
        {name: 'Users', params: {name: 'users'}},
        {name: getUserName(id)}
    ] 
    }
}, {...
```

Answer (score 2):

beforeEach hook might help.

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (!to.meta.breadcrumb) {
    to.meta.breadcrumb = 'your_content'
  }
  next()
})
```